# on click doesn't work for <a> element that has class added by jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a  element that when a check box is checked a class is added and removed from the  element.. Now when the checkbox is checked the class is added to  correctly, however, the  .on('click') handler for that  element with the class added to it is ignored. If I manually add the class to the  element then the .on('click') element is not ignored..

For instance..

When the checkbox is activated it adds the .delete class to the , however, when the  is clicked after the class was added through jquery..the below code is never executed. However, it will work if  the class was hard coded in

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete clicked');

    });
```

Is it just not possible to put a on click event for a element with a class that is added through addClass()? I feel like this is a simple problem ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: sorry...really didn't know it was a repost and I did spend a while searching google for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding and removing the class dynamically would require a delegated event handler, as the element doesn't have the `delete` class when the event handler is attached  :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete clicked');
});
```

replace `document` with the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to listen to the DOM (*The document itself*) instead for newly appended Objects:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function( event ) {
  //code - use Event for preventing 
  //any default behaviour 
});
```

`$('.classdiv').click()` generally only works for currently placed DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete' ,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the jquery selector returns all elements which match at the time the object is created.  It then attaches the event handlers to those elements.  If later an element changes to match or not match that selector, it does not go back and attach or remove handlers.

To get around this, you will need to use event delegation, with `on`.

```
$(STATIC_ANCESTOR).on("click", "a.delete", function(){...
```

Where `STATIC_ANCESTOR` is an ancestor element which will not be re-loaded.  If no other fitting element exists, this can be `document`.  Though for performance reasons you want this element to be as low in the DOM as possible.

You can read more about event delegation in the [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score -1):

use live instead of "on"

```
$('a.delete').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete clicked');

    });
```

Comment: thanks but live() was depreciated in favor of on()..besides that doesn't seem to have answered my question anyway